# Return the total amount of unordered sequences (ABC order) within the string s in Python

Tags: python, loops, count

My code:

```
def inversions(s):
    last = ''
    count = 0
    for letter in s:
        if letter > last:
           count += 1
           last = letter
    return count
```

But I made and error somehwere where it doesnt count properly.
Example calls:

```
inversion('ABBFHDL')
    2
```

But mine returns 5.

Comment: Looks like you just got your greater-than test backwards.

Comment: I think it's more than that - if you flip the `>` to `<`, the `if` block will never be executed because every letter is greater than `''`.

Comment: After I changed it, it returns 0.

Comment: Because, like I said, the `if` block would never be executed. That means `count` would never go up.

Comment: why should return `2`. because order `BB` and `HD`?

Comment: No because of F appears before D and because H comes after D.

Comment: Can you explain how you count these "unordered sequences" in more detail?  The sequences 'HD', 'FHD', 'BFHD', etc all appear here.  Are you just counting unordered letters, not sequences?  (In which case I would just get 1 since if you remove D', everything is in sequence).

Comment: It's just looking through the string for instances of a pair of letters that are out of order. That's why F and D and H and D are the unordered ones because they are "alphabetical".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a sequence is 'unordered' when if you run into the same character or a character that precedes you in order.

```
def solution(str):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(str)-1):
        if str[i] >= str[i+1]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Gives you:

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
 >>>solution('ABBFHDL')
 >>>2
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, to get the total number of unordered sequence is not as easy as your code showed. Below is one way of mine to achieve the target.

Assume the letters in `s` are all uppercase. I use a dictionary to store numbers of letters having visited. And find out how many unordered letters so far by iterating from letter to `Z`

```
def inversions(s):
    nums = dict()
    count = 0
    for ch in s:
        for i in range(ord(ch) + 1,ord('Z')+1):
            count += nums.get(i,0)
        if nums.has_key(ord(ch)):
            nums[ord(ch)] += 1
        else:
            nums[ord(ch)] = 1
    return count
```

Comment: This makes some sense, it's just that we haven't gone over dictionaries yet, and i have to try this using loops. I'm not too sure.